# Computing the Constant Term of a Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Compute

$$\text{const} \left( \frac{1}{(1-z_1z_2)(1-z_1^2z_2)(1-z_1)(1-z_2)z_1^{3t}z_2^{2t}} \right) $$

The answer should be a polynomial in $t$. This is exercise 2.38 from Beck's Computing the Continuous Discretely, and the correct answer is

$$\frac{7}{4} t^2 + \frac{5}{2}t + \frac{7+(-1)^t}{8} $$

I'm honestly at a loss here. Can someone please explain to me how to compute the constant term here? What about a situation where we have a greater number of variables and products of functions?

This is closely related to an earlier post of mine at [Finding Constant Term in Product of Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290516/finding-constant-term-in-product-of-series), which still doesn't have an answer. I would greatly appreciate help on either or both of these problems, and would greatly appreciate a general procedure for doing this. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t know of any short-cuts for this. I think you’re just going to have to bash out the partial fraction expansions and extract coefficients one variable at a time.

Comment: What do we know about $t$?

Comment: Are you sure about that answer? I end up with $7t^2/4$ instead of $7t^2/2$ after assuming that $t\gt0$.

Comment: Oops! I'm so sorry. You are correct. It is $7t^2/4$. And yes, we know that $t>0.$ Can you please show me how you went about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know of any real short cuts for attacking this. I think you just need to bash it out one variable at a time.

Starting from [gt6989b’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3291206/265466), we’re trying to find $[x^{3t}y^{2t}] F(x,y)$ with $g(x,y)$ your generating function (replacing $z_1$ and $z_2$ with $x$ and $y$ to reduce visual clutter) and $F(x,y)=x^{3t}y^{2t}g(x,y)$. Starting with $y$ because it looks like it’ll produce fewer terms, compute the partial fraction expansion with respect to $y$, treating $x$ as a constant: $$\frac1{(1-xy)(1-x^2y)(1-x)(1-y)} = {1 \over (1-x)^3(1+x)(1-y)} - {x \over (1-x)^3(1-xy)} + {x^3 \over (1-x)^3(1+x)(1-x^2y)}$$ and extract the required coefficient of $y$: $$\begin{align} [x^{3t}y^{2t}] F(x,y) &= [x^{3t}]{1 \over (1-x)^3(1+x)} - [x^{3t}]{x^{2t+1} \over (1-x)^3} + [x^{3t}]{x^{4t+3} \over (1-x)^3(1+x)} \\ &= [x^{3t}]{1 \over (1-x)^3(1+x)} - [x^{t-1}]{1 \over (1-x)^3} + [x^{-(t+3)}]{1 \over (1-x)^3(1+x)}. \end{align}$$

Having eliminated $y$, we can now proceed with $x$ in the usual manner. Since $t\gt0$ we can discard the last term. The second term can be evaluated immediately: it’s equal to $-\binom{-3}{t-1} = -\binom{2+t-1}2 = -\frac12t(t+1)$. For the first term, compute the partial fraction expansion and extract coefficients. The resulting sum simplifies to $\frac74t^2+\frac52t+\frac{7+(-1)^t}8$ as required.

Comment: I appreciate the first step, but while I was trying to reconstruct your argument, I wasn't sure what you meant by "extract the required coefficient of $y$" and how I am to do that. Could you please elaborate on how you do the second step when you eliminate $y$? Thank you so much!

Comment: Nevermind! I understand everything. Thank you so much for your input!!!

Comment: amd, would it be possible for you to look at a related problem of mine at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290516/finding-constant-term-in-product-of-series ?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in $f(x)$ as $\left[x^k\right]f(x)$.

You are looking for
$$
\left[x^0 y^0 \right] \frac{F(x,y)}{x^{3t} y^{2t}}
= \left[x^{3t} y^{2t} \right] F(x,y)
$$

Can you now finish it? $F(x,y)$ is just a product of geometric series...

Comment: I understand this notation, and yet, I still don't see how this brings me any closer to solving the problem. As you said, $F(x,y)$ is the product of geometric series, so we can expand what we have into the product of some summations, which gets us to a very nasty summation that involves all the variables. If we examine the exponents of each of the variables in that product, we should get a system of linear equations, right? But I'm not sure how to solve it, since it's actually the same system that I was trying to solve in the first place. Could you please give more information about this?