# In how many ways can $N$ identical balls be distributed among $3$ persons?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $N$ identical balls be distributed among $3$ person, where

1. each of them **gets a distinct number of balls**,
2. and each of them must **get at least one ball**.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @AymanHourieh OK! But first equation makes this more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Ignoring the first condition, we get $\binom {N-1}2$

Now, we need to subtract off the cases in which two of the people got the same number of balls. If we specify the two people, that's $\big \lfloor \frac {N-1}2\big \rfloor$, since the third person has to get at least $1$.  Of course, there are $3$ ways to specify two people.

Now, we see that we have subtracted off the case in which all three people get the same number of balls $3$ times and we only meant to subtract it once.  Thus, in the case where $3\,|\,N$ we must add $2$.

Finally we see that the answer is $$  
\begin{cases}
\binom {N-1}2-3\big \lfloor \frac {N-1}2\big \rfloor  & \text{if $3\nmid N$} \\\\
\binom {N-1}2-3\big \lfloor \frac {N-1}2\big \rfloor +2& \text{if $3\,|\,N$}
\end{cases}$$

Sanity Check:  If $N=9$ this gives $18$.  Indeed, the possible triples are $(6,2,1)$, $(5,3,1)$, and $(4,3,2)$ plus their permutations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since everybody gets a different number of balls, solutions can be partitioned into groups of (exactly) $3!=6$ where the amounts are permuted among the $3$ persons. To count the number of such groups, one can count the number of solutions where numbers are increasing along one fixed ordering, say $A,B,C$, of the three persons, as that picks out one solution from each group.

Now give $1$ ball to $A$, $~2$ balls to $B$, and $3$ balls to $C$, from the stock of $N$. In case $N<6$ one cannot do that, and in those cases there are $0$ solutions. The distribution of the remaining $N-6$ balls is defined by triple $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb N^3$ with $a\leq b\leq c$ and $a+b+c=N-6$. This is essentially a partition of $N-6$ into at most $3$ parts, except that the order is reversed since the convention for partition is to write them as a weakly *decreasing* sequence. The number of such partitions is equal to the number of partitions of $N-6$ into parts not exceeding $3$, with transposition of their Young diagrams giving the bijection. This number is the coefficient of $X^{N-6}$ in the formal power series in $X$ given by
$
  \frac1{(1-X)(1-X^2)(1-X^3)}
$ (the partition with $p$ parts $1$, $q$ parts $2$, and $r$ parts $3$, so that $p+2q+3r=N-6$, corresponds to choosing terms $X^p$ form $\frac1{1-X}$, $X^{2q}$ form $\frac1{1-X^2}$, and $X^{3r}$ form $\frac1{1-X^3}$).

To get the number in the original question, do not forget to multiply by $6$, so a to get the coefficient of the coefficient of the series
$$
  \frac{6X^6}{(1-X)(1-X^2)(1-X^3)}
.$$
This should be a good enough answer for must purposes.

---

If however you want to be more explicit about the dependency on $N$, you can do partial fraction decomposition of that expression, as I illustrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3303414/18880). The decomposition is
$$
  \frac{6X^6}{(1-X)(1-X^2)(1-X^3)}=X^6\left(\frac{47-52X+17X^2}{12(1-X)^3}+\frac{3}{4(1+X)}+\frac{4+2X}{3(1+X+X^2)}\right)
$$
and we can further decompose
$$
  \frac{47-52X+17X^2}{12(1-X)^3}=
  \frac1{(1-X)^3}+\frac3{2(1-X)^2}+\frac{17}{12(1-X)}.
$$
The latter gives the polynomial contribution in $N$, which is
$\binom{N-4}2+\frac32\binom{N-5}1+\frac{17}{12}$, while the remaining two terms give periodic contributions in $N$ of zero average and periods $2$ respectively $3$, namely (starting at $N=6$) the periods $\overline{\frac34,-\frac34}$ and $\overline{\frac43,-\frac23,-\frac23}$, which combine, together with the constant term $\frac{17}{12}$ to
$\overline{\frac72,0,\frac32,2,\frac32,0}$.
Just to check I'll compute this for $N=6,9,13$, which should give respectively $6$, $6\times3=18$ and $6\times8=48$ (for $1$, $3$ and $8$ partitions respectively of $0$, $3$ and $7$). Indeed
$$
  \binom22+\frac32\binom11+\frac72=6, \\
  \binom52+\frac32\binom41+2 = 18, \\
  \binom92+\frac32\binom81+0 = 48. \\
$$